# What does this structure "bully somebody into something/into doing something" mean?

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage

I found this structure "**bully somebody into something/into doing something**" [Source](http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/bully_2)

Ex: *If you’re bullied into doing something illegal*

The structure is strange to me, so it means someone forces you to do something right?

Comment: What an interesting question. Curious as to how you ended up asking this - interesting indeed. :) +1

Comment: @shin, the non-native English speakers think English differently from the native English speakers & that is the main reason why they ask many questions that many native speakers have never asked

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's exactly right. It simply means that they coerce you into doing something or force you to do something that normally you would not do. There is really nothing strange about this type of structure. This is actually a very common pattern in English:

[Example #1](http://dailypost.ng/2015/09/29/the-devil-pushed-me-into-killing-him-suspect-who-buried-friend-in-shallow-grave-photo/):

> The devil pushed me into killing him.

[Example #2](http://edition.cnn.com/2015/11/09/health/snack-advertisers-target-parents/):

> Moms are being manipulated into buying their kids unhealthy food.

It doesn't necessarily have to be a gerund. It can as easily be a noun or a noun phrase:

> Dance with me into oblivion.

Comment: Those are some nasty examples...!

Comment: so besides "*bully somebody into doing something*", we also have "*push / manipulate somebody into doing something*" right? Are there any other verbs that have similar structures?

Comment: I totally agree, but they do help get the point across.

Comment: Correct. I would even go so far as to say that there probably exist a million and one different possibilities that you could twist your sentence into structures like that.

Comment: I would say “Dance…” is no more an example of the pattern than is “We walked together into the park”.